# VBA - Error 3167 Record deleted

Tags: ms-access, vba

I know there's similar posts as this one, but i have not managed to resolve my error by reading them, so i'm posting.

I m trying to make an input form in Ms Access, the user will input two barcodes, and then he ll press a button to commit those values to a table, the process will be repeated until he needs to store said table, in which case there's another button event for that. When they enter each set of records to the input boxes and hit commit, the record is saved, and all the fields are cleared, cursor is going to barcode1 field to await new entries.

The problem starts when, after one successful execution of everything, if i rerun the database, and restart everything, when i try to press the button to commit a new entry into the table, i get the following error:

> Error 3167: Record is Deleted

If i close (x) the application and restart it, everything works normally again.

Here's the relevant code, with the point the debugger gives me the error:

```
Private Sub CommitButton_Click()

    'If (Me!Barcode1 = "**************************") Or IsNull(Me!Barcode1) Or IsNull(Me!Barcode2) Then
    'If (Len(Me!Barcode1) < 2) Or (Len(Me!Barcode2) < 2) Then
    len_barcode1 = Len(Me!Barcode1)
    len_barcode2 = Len(Me!Barcode2)

    If (len_barcode1 < 1 Or IsNull(len_barcode1)) Or (len_barcode2 < 1 Or IsNull(len_barcode2)) Then
        MsgBox ("IS NULL - NOT SAVING")
    Else
       MsgBox ("IS NOT NULL - SAVING")

       fld2 = Barcode2.Value
       fixed = Mid(fld2, 6, 14)
       Barcode2.Value = fixed

       'DoCmd.SetWarnings (WarningsOff)
       DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdSaveRecord
       DoCmd.GoToRecord acDataForm, "BarCodeDataForm", acNext, 1
       Me.Barcode1.SetFocus
       'DoCmd.SetWarnings (WarningsOn)
       Me.Barcode1.Value = Null
       Me.Barcode2.Value = Null
       Me.ValuePrice.Value = Null
       Me.Barcode1.SetFocus    

    End If
End Sub
```

As you see, there is a manual change to a value (Barcode2), the error appears on exactly the next line:

```
DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdSaveRecord
```

Is there a way to commit the changes or resolve this? Thank you

Comment: I think fixed is a reserved word - so would possibly change that just in case it's causing an issue. You are also mixing the way you are referencing the form controls. You have used Me. Me! and dropped the Me completely. Stick to Me.ControlName and drop the .value property - it is the default. I would probably also use `If Me.Dirty Then Me.Dirty = False` to save the record if it's been changed.

Comment: It seems you don't use [`Option Explicit`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bw9t3484%28v=vs.84%29.aspx), which can lead to many hard-to-find errors. To have this automatically in new modules, set the [Require Variable Declaration](http://www.fmsinc.com/microsoftaccess/modules/options/index.html) option in the VBA Editor.